# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android

Скачиваю два списка при помощи Parse.com
Для одного из списков есть условия следующего вида:

```
Integer list_time_table_corr00 = timetable_reservation_list.get(55);
                if (list_time_table_corr00 == 1) {
                    String list_time_table_NEWDATA00 = newdata.get(55);
                    dateTitletext.setText(list_time_table_NEWDATA00);

                    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("timeTable", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor sedt = sp.edit();
                    sedt.putString("timeTable", dateTitletext.getText().toString());
                    sedt.apply();}
```

Вопрос в том, что, когда выключен Интернет и невозможно скачать оба списка, приложение думает, что список ничего не содержит, как я понимаю, и выдает app crashed и ошибку: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 55, size is 0`
Пробовал включить проверку на наличие интернета, но тогда не работает другой метод, нужный мне. 
Как "сказать" программе, что, если список пустой, ничего не делай?
Пробовал прописать пустое условие else -  не работает, все равно вызывает эту ошибку.

Условия для скачивания из Parse.com:

```
for (ParseObject po : list) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                Integer c = list.get(i).getInt("change");
                                timetable_reservation_list.add(c);
                                list_time_table.add(po.getObjectId());
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, "timetable_reservation_list" + timetable_reservation_list);
                        }
```

Comment: А что такое `timetable_reservation_list` и `newdata`? У них в методах и ищите проверку на пустоту

Comment: Если `timetable_reservation_list` и `newdata` это списки, т.е. List. Тогда можно использовать метод `isEmpty()`. Но он вернет `false`, если в списках есть хотя бы один элемента, а вам надо взять 55. Так что по моему вам надо какие-то другие условия. Какие именно, надо исходить из логики вашего приложения.

Comment: @BOPOH , это 2 списка, которые мне нужно скачать. Я добавил небольшой код, при помощи которого я скачиваю, в вопрос. Вы могли бы помочь мне разобраться, как сделать так, чтобы не вылетало?

Comment: У вас какие-то странные циклы. Вы и во внешнем и во внутреннем проходите по одному и тому же списку, это так и надо?

Comment: @Vartlok, вряд ли, просто я новичок и только пытаюсь разобраться. Сейчас главная задача - решить вопрос с вылетом, вот и пытаюсь его решить. В таком коде как-то можно проверить на пустоту списка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если принять за условие, что списки всегда заполняются либо корректно, либо никак. То можно использовать метод `isEmpty()`. Код будет таким:

```
if (!timetable_reservation_list.isEmpty() && !newdata.isEmpty()) {
    Integer list_time_table_corr00 = timetable_reservation_list.get(55);
    if (list_time_table_corr00 == 1) {
        String list_time_table_NEWDATA00 = newdata.get(55);
        dateTitletext.setText(list_time_table_NEWDATA00);

        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("timeTable", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor sedt = sp.edit();
        sedt.putString("timeTable", dateTitletext.getText().toString());
        sedt.apply();
    }
}
```

Если же моё предположение не верное, то можно проверять на длину списков, т.е. условие будет `timetable_reservation_list.size()>55 && newdata.size()>55`

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Вы очень помогли!